# How to fix sum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example code

```py
a = [1,2,3]
print(sum(a))
```

Error traceback shown

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8c9e0f297c95> in <module>
      1 a = [1,2,3]
----> 2 print(sum(a))

TypeError: sum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: Python's built-in function `sum()` would not produce that message. Make sure you haven't defined your function named "sum"?

Comment: Try `print(builtins.sum(a))`. You will need to `import builtins`. to bypass your override.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined your own `sum` method that takes different parameters.  For example, if I run this cell:

```py
def sum(x, y):
    return x + y
```

followed by a cell with your code:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
print(sum(a))
```

I get the same error output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8c9e0f297c95> in <module>
      1 a = [1,2,3]
----> 2 print(sum(a))

TypeError: sum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

To fix this, you can either rename your `sum` function to something else (such as `my_sum`), then go to the Kernel menu and click Restart, or use `builtins.sum` as [suggested by Mike67 in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223384/how-to-fix-sum-missing-1-required-positional-argument-y#comment111798588_63223384):

```py
import builtins
a = [1,2,3]
builtins.sum(a)
```

I would recommend renaming the function to avoid the conflict, as you may run into other conflicts later.  It's generally a good practice to avoid defining anything with the same name as a built-in function.

Answer (score -1):

```
import builtins 

def sum_all(*args):
    return builtins.sum(args) 

sum_all(1,2,3,4)
```

I was also doing same mistake while defining a function and using sum function and it kept giving me TypeError, so I imported bulitins and passed *args as parameter and got the sum.